# Error message during Partitioning

Tags: partitioning

I use Ubuntu $16.04$ LTS. I'm talking about my Laptop's internal Hard drive. It's 500 GB. I'll retrieve the exact details once power comes back(bad battery).Whenever I used "DISK" or "GParted" on my Hard Drive, I get the following error message:

```
The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it's 512 bytes.
```

I see an option to **ignore** or **cancel**. I always click ignore, I want to know if I should be worried. I see the message once I open DISK or GParted immediately the utility finishes scanning my hard drive. I was trying to re-partition my system so I can run Windows, Ubuntu and Kali. I am a noob who just installed Ubuntu today, and has no prior experience with Linux.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what $$ and $$ are exactly.

Comment: It sounds like you have a UEFI formatted partition and are trying to use a Legacy partition manager on it.

Comment: Please provide more details. What version Ubuntu? What are you trying to do when you get that error? What disk and how is it connected... ie: laptop internal disk, SATA Western Digital, etc. How about the `terminal output of `sudo fdisk -l` and/or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I believe I use UEFI(not sure what it means). I use [DISK] and [GPARTED] in Ubuntu and [DISK MANAGEMENT] in Windows.

Comment: You can't use `gparted` in Ubuntu that's for legacy. You need to use `GPT` which is for UEFI. I haven't used EFI myself yet although it's like 4 years old on my laptop.... ultimate procrastinator!

Comment: I think it's fine. Some of the hard drives have bigger physical block sizes. It has nothing to do with MBR or GPT (which is the way how partition info is stored). I believe (but might be wrong) that OS or hard drive  might be emulating 512 byte block sizes for legacy reasons.

So I would just try repartitioning anyway (but make sure you have backups because cases like this might be less tested).